# Calculus Exponential Functions Again

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

This one wants us to evaluate the following limits of this exponential function.

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac6{e^x-6}$$

I'm not sure how to approach this problem. I did easily figure out this version of the problem when x approached negative infinity.

Comment: Think of it in this way: $(e^x - 6)\to \infty$ as $x\to \infty$, $\frac{6}{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, when $x \to +\infty, e^x \to +\infty$, so the whole thing goes to zero.  Can you make that more precise?

Comment: I'm not sure where to start. Hurkyl above said to start plugging in x = +infinty, and it seems to start from negative and starts going into the positive area... and then starts to go down to roughly 0 again.

Comment: Oh... OH. Okay. Figured that out.

Answer (score 0):

All of the parts of the function are continuous where defined, including at $-\infty$ and $+\infty$, so you can just plug in $x = +\infty$.

If you aren't comfortable with the extended real numbers, going through the exercise of plugging in $x = +\infty$ should at least give a hint about what's going on.

Comment: Oh... OH. Okay. Figured that out. Thanks very much.